# Consume WCF service programmatically in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to be able to consume a WCF Service endpoint in my Windows Phone 8 app.

Searching on Google only showed me that I had to Right-Click on the WP8 Project, select 'Add Service Reference'... Which is not a viable solution in my case.

- I want to be able to consume a WCF service inside my Windows Phone 8 app, *programmatically*.
- Where do I define my client endpoint certificate in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Imagine that I want to make a Windows Phone 8 app, which should be able to connect to a WCF service hosted on another device, i.e. a computer. Then the WP user needs to enter the hostname of that computer in order to be able to connect to the WCF service.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "baaah!" ?

Comment: Ok, but why ? What are you trying to do that is not handled properly by the proxy generator ?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. This is now explained in a comment to @cad 's answer.

Comment: @KristianB: My suggestion is that you edit your question with relevant info (even if it is already in the comment to my answer)

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to use "Add Service Reference" to generate the proxy class.
The DTO and Client proxy will be automatically generated. You will benefit from a huge boost in productivity, type safety and name checking.

Then you can specify the url at runtime using the appropriate constructor. For instance :

```
private MyServiceClient GetMyServiceClient(string url)
{
  Uri uri = new Uri(url);
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
  EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
  MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
  return client;
}
```

(MySericeClient being the generated proxy)

The *.config* stuff is optional, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a Service Reference, your WP8 Project is auto generating a proxy class that wraps the WCF Service. Then your code uses this proxy class.

The other way of doing this is creating the proxy class manually, and believe me, you want to avoid this if you can...

Comment: Imagine that I want to make a Windows Phone 8 app, which should be able to connect to a WCF service hosted on another device, i.e. a computer. Then the WP user needs to enter the hostname of that computer in order to be able to connect to the WCF service.

Comment: In a normal app, the hostname is store in the **app.config**. I am sure you can override the hostname read there and use one that you manually request from the user...

Answer (score 0):

1. Proxy Client class generated by Add Service Reference will use hostname (endpoint address) from config only when you use its parameterless constructor. You can specify endpoint adress manually at runtime of course.
2. You can create service contract portable class library and share it between client and server. Then you dont have to generate proxy classes, but you use ChannelFactory API: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/channel-factory-in-wcf/